# Autofit Target cell but only when content is larger

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using the following piece of vba inside my Worksheet_Change Sub to autosize a particular column with text entries:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim nextTarget As Range

Set nextTarget = Range(Selection.Address) 'store the next range the user selects

If Target.Column = 1 Then

    Target.Columns.Select 'autofit requires columns to be selected
    Target.Columns.AutoFit

    nextTarget.Select
End If
End Sub
```

The above has the problem that every time you enter in a cell of that column text which is shorter than the other cells, it will shrink the column to fit the target cell, leaving the other cells with text outside. Is there any addition that I could make to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.EntireColumn` method. With this there is no need to `Select` any cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'added extra error trapping in case something happens where more than 1 column is changed.
If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then 

    Target.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End If

End Sub
```